# Sri Madhvacharya's interpretation for mahAnArAyanOpanisad

Tags: madhvacharya, mahanarayana-upanishad

Can someone point me to Sri Madhvacharya's interpretation of Taittiriya MahA nArAyanOpanisad? Thanks in advance. Any text on the interpretation of the entire taittiriya AranyakA is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MadhvAchArya did not write a commentary on the Mahanarayana upanishad.

The following are the works of Madhva as given by [B N K Sharma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._N._Krishnamurti_Sharma) in his work [A History of the Dvaita School of Vedānta and Its Literature](https://www.amazon.in/History-Dvaita-School-Vedanta-Literature/dp/8120815750).

[image]
[image]

There is no mention of any commentary on Mahanarayana upanishad by Madhva.

Comment: Thank you @yAdRcchika Perhaps I misunderstood something, I thought His Holiness Sri Madvacharya commented on the Taittiriya Aranyaka. So I was looking to see if there is a commentary on The nArAyanOpanisad.